# I just installed popOS and upon upgrading the system I get this error:

Tags: ubuntu, amd-graphics, pop-os

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_dmcu.bin for module amdgpu
```

My graphics card is Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]).

Comment: This may help https://askubuntu.com/a/1124256/130536

Answer (score 0):

The package `firmware-amd-graphics` provides these files.

`sudo apt install firmware-amd-graphics`

---

How did I figure this out?

```
$ apt-file search /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_gpu_info.bin
firmware-amd-graphics: /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_gpu_info.bin
```

`apt-file` is a tool that can tell us which packages provide each file.

---

Pop-OS comes from Ubuntu which comes from Debian but I've found that Ubuntu does not ship this package.  Instead, Ubuntu has merged the content of this package with `linux-firmware` per [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1638831).  Try to install `linux-firmware`.  If that doesn't work, use `apt-file` to find which package provides these files yourself.

Comment: After i run "sudo apt install firmware-amd-graphics it returns 

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package firmware-amd-graphics is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'firmware-amd-graphics' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Unfortunatley I don't have a PopOS machine to test this on.  I found some info on the Ubuntu version of the package which I added to the answer.  If that doesn't work: what's the output of the `apt-file` command I showed?  (you may need to install `apt-file` then `apt update` to tell me)

Comment: So after using your suggestion I have this output: pastebin.com/wwGSWund